NextJs 14 automatically send cookies in server components with axios
I'm settings a cookie in client side and there I'm also settings axios to send the cookie with all the request, it works in client components but in server component axios is not sending the cookie even tho I'm using the same instance of axios.
Here's how I'm setting cookie
"use client";
import { setCookie } from "cookies-next";
...
const onClick = v => setCookie("lng", v);
....

In axios
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

Even when I do this in server component it won't send it
const getInfo = async (lng) => axios.get("/info", {headers: {Cookie: `lng=${lng}`}}); 

Any solution?
